# Mixed strategy in ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to run a set of Ansible tasks with free strategy (all tasks running at the same time). And once they all are done, run another set from within the same playbook?

Importing second playbook could work, but even so, I'm not quite sure how Ansible will handle free strategy execution and playbook import.

Comment: Strategies are not about running tasks at the same time.

Comment: You could fire a series of async steps and then wait_for them before doing more. Why does that not suffice? What have you tried?

Comment: @techraf. You are right, I wrongly wrote it that way because I have specific tasks for each remote machine in the same playbook. It should be  something like "all remote hosts running independently".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A strategy is tied to a play so you cannot change strategy in the middle of the play however you can put several plays in the same playbook just for the sake of mixing strategies.

```
- name: a play to run all tasks as fast as we can
  hosts: servers
  strategy: free
  tasks:

  ...

- name: a play to run each task on each server before going to the next one    
  hosts: servers
  strategy: linear
  tasks:
```

Comment: Do you know if the second play will be executed once all tasks from first play are done?

Comment: yes, the second play will be started once all tasks from the first play will be finished.